# Targeting Specific Style Sheets only for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad

Since Safari browser for mobile devices (iPhones and iPads) doesn't fully support Tahoma font,so want to set Arial font for iPhones and iPads only.  So how can I set font type Arial only for iPhone and iPad, and other os will have Tahoma font.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

To Targeting Specific Style Sheets iPad and iPhone Please put this code in your `<head>` tag:

```
 <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="http://example.com/iPhone.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="http://example.com/iPad.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abrar. 
But I guess it will affect android as well. I need only iPhone and iPad specific.

Comment: use this one for the ipad :  @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
{
/* Your iPad specific rules here */
}

Comment: Thanks ... I will try this.